# How to add a trailing line under a header in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to add an underline under my header that trails to the left side of the page. I want the header to be able to line up with the start of the content beneath it but am having difficulty doing the CSS for it. I've tried using hr element, styling a div and grouping the header with it, and other ways, but can't seem to get it to the trail to the edge of the page.

[image: figma description of image]

Here is what it currently looks like.

[image: current implementation]

Here is some of the HTML that is rendering it:

```
 <div class="page__item page__item--left">
      <h2 class="page__header__title page__header__title--ltr">
          EXPERIENCE
      </h2>
  <div class="page__header__line"></div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think we need to see your existing CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it and set width.

```
h2:before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   left: -20px;
   bottom: -20px;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #506e73;
   width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: This seems fairly close. The only issue is when I try to resize the page, the line doesn't go with experience when I resize the screen. I tried adjusting the width to be a percentage instead, but no luck yet. Using before seems to be the right direction, is there a way I can "attach" it in a sense to the text?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea using [border-image](https://twitter.com/ChallengesCss/status/1537394975066972161)

```css
.full-line {
  border-image: 
   linear-gradient(0deg,#1095c1 5px,#0000 0) fill 0//0 0 0 100vw;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: fit-content;
}


section {
  /* center + max-width:800px + min-margin: 10px */
  margin-inline: max(10px, 50% - 800px/2);
  margin-block: 50px; 
}
body {
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  background: #eee;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align:justify;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1 class="full-line">Main title</h1>
  <p>Dragée powder bear claw tiramisu pudding gummi bears wafer. Macaroon chocolate cake cake marzipan icing carrot cake macaroon sweet. Lemon drops </p>
</section>
<section>
  <h2>Secondary title</h2>
  <p >Pie pastry macaroon candy tootsie roll jujubes pudding pie. Jelly-o chocolate cake pastry gingerbread brownie danish liquorice chocolate cake. Jelly beans donut cupcake danish croissant liquorice. Cotton candy brownie croissant pie toffee. Cotton candy chocolate cake gummi bears ice cream jelly fruitcake caramels. Shortbread ice cream bear claw gingerbread chocolate cake jelly-o cake caramels soufflé.</p>
</section>
<section>
  <h3>another title</h3>
  <p>Pie pastry macaroon candy tootsie roll jujubes pudding pie.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for! Are there supposed to be these two slashes "0//0"? I'm getting a syntax error here.